# Uniqueness of the integral of the postive and negative parts of a function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

A problem I have been thinking about but not sure if it is right or not.

Claim: Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f,g$ be real-valued measurable, $L^1$ functions. If $\int_A f\,d\mu = \int_A g\,d\mu$ for all $A\in \mathcal{M}$, then $\int_A f^+\,d\mu = \int_A g^+\,d\mu$ and $\int_A f^-\,d\mu = \int_A g^-\,d\mu$ for all $A\in\mathcal{M}$.

Would appreciate a quick proof or a counterexample, but a reference is fine too.

Comment: From $\int_A f\,d\mu = \int_A g\,d\mu$ for all $A\in \mathcal{M}$ it follows that $f=g$ almost everywhere, so the positive and negative parts are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A=\{x:f(x)>g(x)\}$. Then $\int_A f\,d\mu=\int_A g\,d\mu$ implies $A$ has measure $0$ (perhaps more straightforwardly seen by considering $h=f-g$).  Similarly, $\{x:f(x)<g(x)\}$ has measure $0$, so $f=g$ a.e. as Blaza commented.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, does a.e. equality also hold if $\int_A f\,d\mu = \int_A f\,d\mu$ for all $A\in\mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: That would follow if you can show that the set of $A$ where equality holds is a sigma algebra.

Comment: @Satana To add to Jonas's comment, by Dynkin's lemma, it suffices for $\mathcal{E}$ to be a $\pi$-system (generating $\mathcal{M}$).